# Didn't find any proper resolution

Tags: display-resolution

I install Ubuntu on my desktop, but I can't find the 1920x1080 resolution. I use it on windows but can't find that on Ubuntu. Any advice!!

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome Tirtho.
Please for this u need to find the name that your OS give to the Screen trough this command:

```
xrandr --listactivemonitors
```

that will give u back something like this:

```
    Monitors: 2
 0: +*XWAYLAND0 1600/430x900/240+1920+0  XWAYLAND0
 1: +XWAYLAND1 1920/480x1080/270+0+0  XWAYLAND1
```

The very first thing u can try is:

```
cvt 1920 1080 60.0
```

this will show you the Modeline of that resolution like this:

```
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

from this u will use right after Modeline : "1920x1080_60.00".... with the xrandr command like this:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

now add that modeline to the name of your monitor, on this example:

```
xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND0 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

Now it's time to add this mode on a little config file created on your home nano or vi called .xprofile

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND0 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

now do this to it initialize every time u log in to your user:

```
chmod +x $HOME/.xprofile
```